# Laravel policy autodetect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

today i was creating USER profile page with is controlled in `ProfileController` it returning views to profile page, profile settings, etc.

so i decide to make some Policy rules to Edit profile and etc.

so i found i should use Middleware / Gates / Policy, based on Laravel Doc i chose Policy because profil page is public but only specific part of it can author edit so i needed @can

So my steps:

1. `php artisan make:policy ProfilePolicy` ( without model )
2. Registered policy to `AuthServiceProvider` in `$policies` property
3. writed methods like `edit` inside `ProfilePolicy`

then i started thinking how i define it to my Controller hmmm, documentation doesnt helps me :/

so i tryed blade `@can('edit', $user)` method and it worked, but **HOW** ?, how to define specific policy to one Controller ? ( not Model ), how to define multiple Policy to single Controller

i m lost how laravel Magic done this maybe because of Naming ? ProfileController => ProfilePolicy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller you can write this

```
public function edit(Profile $profile) {
   $this->authorize('edit', $profile)
}
```

Laravel does this:

- Check the type of `$profile`, and it's a `Profile::class`
- Check policies registered for that class (your step 2)
- Looks for the `edit` method in that policy, if not found, return false meaning user is *not* authorized
- Executes the `edit()` function that returns true/false

In blade the `@can` directive does exactly the same thing.

Policies are meant to be tied to Models, it's a convenient way to write rules to handle single models, but they can be triggered in many ways (like the `authorize()` method in controllers and `@can` directive in blade).

Comment: ehh, i know i can but this will be okey for Edit POST request or Edit Ajax data for example, ut if you have page for multiple task wher eyou want to add Inline edditing you cant use it like this,
also i want to know how laravel figures out with policy he should pair to my controller + view ( with is returned by controller ), and also how to define custom policy for controller like 123132321Policy ( without Name pair )

Comment: I think I have clearly explained how Laravel understand which Policy is associated with which model.

Remember that a policy can be defined **only** for models, not controller.

Comment: so its inpasible give random Policy to random controller ?  for example  TestController  and TestNewPolicy ?

Comment: Again, policy applies to MODELS no Controllers.

Comment: Al i dont have Profile Model so it have to bind to controller, also controllers returning views and you can use @can method, then how without model ... ?

Comment: Third time I say this. Policies are bound to MODELS so, in order to have a policy you _MUST_ have a model. 

Maybe there is some misunderstanding. Can you explain me what did you do in point 2 of your post?

Comment: ```  User::class  => ProfilePolicy::class, ``` so its bound on UserModer this is why i can use @can   on User, now i understand